# unwanted scrollbar on the print preview and not showing the 2nd page of the document

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in my windows.print() 
the datas I am trying to print exceeds 1 page and I can't see a 2nd page as the continuation of the datas but it rather shows a scroll bar on the print preview

Answer (score 2):

Try using this in your `print.css`:

```
body {overflow-y: hidden;}
```